# ng click and/or ng change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony, twig

Morning, here is what happens.

I made a dev, it was working fine, but only with firefox.
When i tested it with chrome...it wasn't working at all.

So, I have a select and I want to save the selected value to deal with it later.

Here is my angular:

```
 if ($scope.dateTemp == "") {
     $scope.displayNotification('error', "Empty date");
 } else {
     alert($scope.dateTemp);
     //dateTemp treatment
 }
```

AND

```
$scope.saveDate = function(dateMin){
            alert(dateMin);
            $scope.dateTemp=dateMin;
        };
```

My view:

```
<p>Select date
    <br/>
    <select ng-model="date_selection" ng-change="saveDate(dateMin)">
        <option ng-repeat="dateMin in listeDate" track by $index>{[{dateMin}]}</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

When i tried this, i got undefined with my alert (btw saveDate function is just a setter for `$scope.dateTemp`)

Moreover when i try this, it works fine, but not with chrome.

```
    <select ng-model="date_selection">
        <option ng-click="saveDate(dateMin)" ng-repeat="dateMin in listeDate" track by $index>{[{dateMin}]}</option>
    </select>
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: You have syntax error. It should be  ng-repeat="dateMin in listeDate track by $index"

Comment: I did that, but i'm still getting undefined when i tried to print dateMin

Comment: You should print it like {{dateMin}} not {[{dateMin}]}

Comment: No, because this is inside Symfony and i have conflict with twig.
So i defined those opening and closing tags.

The matter is not in the list herself...i see the content of the list, no problem with that...the problem is that i can't get the selected data.

Comment: Show your saveDate function. You have to pass ur ng-model in saveData function

Comment: $scope.saveDate = function(dateMin){
       alert(dateMin);
       $scope.dateTemp=dateMin;
   };

Comment: @Minirock, have a look to my answer, `date_selection` is the date selected

Comment: @Minirock, i added saveDate function to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`track by $index` should be included in the `ng-repeat` directive.

```
<select ng-model="date_selection" ng-change="saveDate(dateMin)">
        <option ng-repeat="dateMin in listeDate track by $index">{[{dateMin}]}</option>
</select>
```

`track by` is an option of `ng-repeat` directive which helps to identify unique every item in the array.

Short example:

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.date_selection;
  $scope.listeDate = ['date1','date2'];
  $scope.saveDate=function(date_selection){
    console.log(date_selection);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
   <select ng-model="date_selection" ng-change="saveDate(date_selection)">
        <option ng-repeat="dateMin in listeDate">{{dateMin}}</option>
   </select>
   {{date_selection}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I test it and it works in chrome and mozilla.

Comment: I did that, but i'm still getting undefined when i tried to print dateMin

Comment: Should i do saveDate(date_selection) ?

Comment: @Minirock, sure, have a look to answer.

Comment: It works fine now with my local firefox...i will push that and see if it's ok mais chrome now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **ng-options** inside select tag

Controller :

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.listeDate = [{"value":1,"text":"date1"},
  {"value":2,"text":"date2"},
  {"value":3,"text":"date3"},
  {"value":4,"text":"date4"}];

  $scope.Print=function(){
    alert($scope.selected);
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-options="date.value as date.text for date in listeDate" ng-model="selected" ng-change="Print()"></select>
  </body>
```

Working plunker [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/WI1jzFkKHEm5BaCvS31Q?p=preview)